# How to get the corresponding var of a function parameter in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Consider the following Clojure REPL commands:

```
user=> (defn foobar [x] (println x))
#'user/foobar
user=> (defn somefun [] )
#'user/somefun
user=> (foobar somefun)
#object[user$somefun 0x4efeab94 user$somefun@4efeab94]
nil
user=> (foobar (var somefun))
#'user/somefun
nil
```

Question: how can I achieve that `foobar` prints the `var`-form of its parameter?

This does not work:

```
(defn foobar [x] (println (var x)))
```

Result:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve var: x in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init882462612882384638.clj:1:27)
```

It does not work with `(defn foobar [x] (println #'x))` either (same result).

Answer (score 1):

> how can I achieve that `foobar` prints the `var`-form of its parameter?

I'm not sure this is possible using a `defn` function. Once you're in the body of `foobar`, `x` is a function value (not a symbol) and `var` expects a symbol argument. You can resolve the var *before* calling the function, or you could use a macro which allows you to work with the function's symbol:

```
(defmacro print-var [x]
  `(println (var ~x)))

(print-var somefun)
;; #'user/somefun
```

Comment: So a "variable", which is a function parameter, and a "global" "variable" are different things in Clojure? (I know this is not the right terminology, hence the quotation marks, just I'm not sure what is their common name -- if they have one at all.)